# Import Avada Demos error - Demo server couldn't be reached. Please check for wp_remote_get on the System Status page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I am having a problem with Avada Demos, when I try to import one of its demos I get the following **error message**:

> Demo server couldn't be reached. Please check for wp_remote_get on the
>   System Status page

I've checked what the error message suggests and that is not the problem. I've also checked some other things but couldn't seem to fix it.

Has anyone had this problem before? If so, how do I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Also had this problem. In my case, it was a permission problem for the wp-content folder. After giving the proper write permissions, the import of demo content worked.

Comment: Please improve the answer bu providing step by step instructions. Attach sources if possible.

Comment: This is a very lacking answer, but it *is* an answer.

Comment: I had to re-install Avada. Once I did that, everything without any problem. But I still don't know the reason for the error.